# Use client in event with event handler and ...args | Discord.js@13

Tags: javascript, discord.js, args

I would like to use the `client` in the event, but I don't know how to hand it over without removing `... args`

the event handler:

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });



const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}
```

and the event modul:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(client,interaction) {
       
   //... need client from code before here

    },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `client` to the args!

```js
if (event.once) {
  client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(client, ...args));
} else {
  client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(client, ...args));
}
```